# Communicating with SQL Database with Arduino and Tracking Shield Sim900A

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, sim900

Since Last many days I am trying to Send the Data to SQL Data base via GPRS. I tried doing many program, like using AT commands, but none works.

I am using Aurdino Uno R3 and Tracking Shield sim 900A from Rhydolabz

Comment: Please break down for us what does work and what doesn't.. From this question the problem could be that you get no power, or that you don't know how to write a SQL Select statement..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but  The problem is solved. I had to just Flip the Switch on GSM BOARD (Sim 900A) from Arduino to USB. All AT commands are Running Successfully. And also I am able to Send the data to my Server. Thank you .